# Bash Cluster Monitor - Help for assignment

Tags: bash

I am a student at university and I am stuck with some code for my assignment, and would appreciate the help from the community with this. I am very new to bash, and I would say that I do not know how to write bash at all, I struggle with it. I much prefer python or C# lol. Anyways, I am required to create a cluster monitor. I have got to create a simple menu with 2 options that allows the user to choose between the options "Cluster Status" and "Process Analytics". I have created the menu, it's very basic, and the code for that is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo="Choose one of the following options: "
echo="1) Cluster Status"
echo="2) Process Analytics"
echo="3) Exit"
read ans:
        if ["$ans"=='1']
        then
                 echo="Loading..."
                 bash Cluster_Status.sh
        elif ["$ans"=='2']
        then
                 echo="Loading..."
                 bash Process_Analytics.sh
        elif ["$ans"=='3']
        then
                 echo="Loading..."
```

In this menu, I also need to make it so that when it has completed execution, it pauses and returns to the main menu.

I have got 5 nodes for the cluster, with sample data in them, which can be provided if anyone wants to help with this.

The part that I am most stuck with is the creating of the cluster status and the process analytics part of this.
The cluster status is a script that provides a screen and file printout of the current stats of the entire cluster, with all of its parameters set in a nodeconfig.read.me file, which I have got. The stats need to be presented either in a sum or as an average. For example, the total amount of CPUs would be a sum, and the total CPU load would be an average. I need to do this in a table, which I cannot figure out how to do, as I am limited by the amount of different functions I can use.

The process analytics section asks me to process the current processes that are running on each node, if there are any, and I need to present the following stats onscreen and also have it saved to a file:

•   Most popular process (in terms of instances running)
•   Most CPU demanding process (in terms of CPU usage)
•   Most MEM demanding process (in terms of Memory usage)
•   Most Disk demanding process (in terms of Disk usage)
•   Most Net demanding process (in terms of Network usage)
•   5 top users of CPU/MEM/DISK & Net (separate tables)

I have got to do this in PuTTy, so I am limited to the built in functions of PuTTy, cat, grep, ls, pipe, echo, tr, tee, cut, touch, head, tail. These are the only things that I can use when writing this, and because of the limitation, I am stuck when trying to find how to write this. I have researched how to do this for the last week, and I still do not know how to complete this. I do not ask for this assignment to be completed by anyone. I just want to ask for help on how to use these commands to be able to create this script. Thank you for your help from now, and I am sorry if this is posted in the wrong area. I am still fairly new with using stackoverflow.

Comment: A tall challenge - as you say no one here can write this for your specific case - but you mentioned you have a few unix commands in your toolbag already - Are you able to check if you have access to monitoring tools such as iotop , ps , htop, ipstat, netstat ? Running them natively will return too much information - but using the man pages and --help switches will get you started in the right direction - happy to take this offline

Comment: Bookmark https://shellcheck.net should be the very first thing you need to do, paste your script at that site to validate it. The builtin/keyword `select` can create a menu for you which should do what you wanted about a menu. Good luck with the assignment.